# Trouble installing Homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew

I have just started learning Ruby on Rails and am having a little trouble getting the environment set up on a Macbook Air OS X version 10.9.3

I installed Ruby from rvm.io

I have:
Ruby 2.0.0p451
Rails 4.1.4
Git 1.7.4.4
XCode version 2003 (is this wrong?)

I used `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"`

but I get back `Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --install`

I looked around and I have seen that people suggest Homebrew not be installed using sudo access, but it keeps asking for my password. What am I doing wrong here? Why does Homebrew refuse to install?

Comment: check this out http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Comment: Did you enable "root" user? [look here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528)

Comment: Homebrew is designed to not use root. Either way when I run it in sudo it still has the same errors as above

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact version of XCode? 5.1.1? The failed command is to install XCode command line tool. Probably you can install that first before installing Ruby.

Comment: Yes Xcode 5.1.1 is installed. Still getting the same errors after installing the command line tools via Apple dev downloads.

Comment: Also, when I run `xcode-select --install` it just says `xcode version 2003` even after I manually downloaded the xcode command line tools via the Apple dev downloads.